# About how to compose retrograde analysis problems

Tags: retrograde-analysis, composing

Are there any books or articles devoted to *composing* retrograde analysis problems? It seems that you would need some techniques beyond ones for standard problems.

Comment: This is not the answer, but may be you will find this interesting: http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/chessnum/

Comment: This is neither an answer, but you surely can study a lot of problems to get a hang of the techniques used (a specialist periodical with commented solutions is beneficial). There is even a special terminology for all the techniques (random example: look up what a retro shield is).

Comment: The link www2.stetson etc is dead. Does anyone have a copy of this doc?

Comment: https://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/puzzle/chessnum/ appears to be live.
This is not retrograde analysis, as there is no requirement (or indeed possibility!) of legality, but is amusing and it looks as if there are other chess-related puzzle types on the site.

Answer (score 3):

See my answer to [About retrograde analysis](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/5583/about-retrograde-analysis/8627#8627). The Retro Corner is not about *composing.* but it has lots of easy and hard examples with detailed solutions, comments, etc.